# Virtual hosts dymanic accept all incoming domain requests

Tags: virtualhost, cname-record

I have the system with Apace.

In `httpd-vhosts.conf`, I configured to accept subdomains, like below:

```
<virtualhost *:80>
   ServerName www.mydomainname.com
   ServerAlias mydomainname.com *.mydomainname.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The system works very well, dynamically I could create subdomains, such as `http://example.mydomainname.com` ; it works normally

And now I have a custom domain `acustomdomain.com`, and I want to point this domain to `example.mydomainname.com` & use acustomdomain.com to browse web content of `example.mydomainname.com`

So, on `acustomdomain.com`, I created a `CNAME (www)` & pointed to `example.mydomainname.com`; but it only displays the config page of mydomainname.com ; not content of `www.mydomainname.com` or `example.mydomainname.com`

May tell me this solution (CNAME) is right? Or I need to do more tasks?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The point is: CNAME is an alias to example.mydomainname.com, which resolves into ip address. So when you type in your browser acustomdomain.com DNS gives you ip of example.mydomainname.com . That's the only thing CNAME does. So in your request to server you will have http-header "Host: acustomdomain.com". Apache knows nothing about it, but there is Default config, which, if no matches in ServerName or ServerAlias is found, gives you some default page (as you said: displays the config page of mydomainname.com) 
So you have to add new virtual host with ServerName acustomdomain.com or add one more ServerAlias in mydomain.com, depending of what you want to get.

Comment: thank for explaining, I tried `ServerAlias mydomainname.com *.mydomainname.com www.acustomdomain.com` but it doesn't work

and `acustomdomain.com` is random, I can't setup manually, there's any dynamic solution?

thanks

Comment: what do you mean random? You can always use wildcard (*) as default for non matching ServerName domains

Comment: basically, my site allow users create sudomain, then use their custom domains point to these subdomains, but I don't know how to capture these custom domains

Comment: now I see, it's kinda hosting. So, anyway there must be some interface to change apache virtual hosts (ServerAlias) , otherwise it won't be able to guess which directory root it should use

Comment: yes, exactly, I want to establish a system like hosting, but I really don't know how to build; please help me, many thanks